# Filtering out coordinates from MultiPolygon with turf.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, geospatial, turfjs

I've got 2 collections of locations (features1 and features2), and would like to remove all the overlaps from the locations. When the locations from both collections are of type Polygon it's rather simple, I can just use turf.difference(feature1, feature2) and overwrite feature1 with the result, thus removing any overlay. Although this operation can return a MultiPolygon in cases where the overlap splits the Polygon, which is correct, but that complicates this process as feature1 can have multiple overlaps from feature2, and turf.difference will only work for the first. I would therefore like a way to filter out the coordinates without turf.difference. There are cases where feature1 has overlaps from 7 different feature2, and the first one works great but afterwards things go south.

I've tried using another turf-function, namely turf.coordEach which iterates through all the coordinates, and then checking whether the coordinates exists in feature2, if yes, remove the coordinates from the feature1 MultiPolygon-array. The function currently looks like this:

```
if (type === 'MultiPolygon') {

    //Iterates through all the coords in the MultiPolygon
    turf.coordEach(
      feature1,
      function (
        currentCoord,
        coordIndex,
        featureIndex,
        multiFeatureIndex,
        geometryIndex
      ) {
        //Checks whether the current coordinates exists in feature2
        if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(currentCoord, feature2)) {
          feature1.geometry.coordinates.splice(coordIndex, 1)
        }
      }
    )

    //Should update the Location in the DB after the coordinates are spliced.
    return await Location.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: feature._id },
      { $set: feature as any },
      { upsert: true, new: true }
    ).exec()
  }
```

I'd guess the splice is where this fails, but I can't figure out how to do it and there double/triple/quadruple-nested arrays confuses me. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself incase someone else stumbles upon the same issue in the near future. It's a known issue that will be merged in the next release. Here's the [link](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/2344) to the PR.